# Determines whether a number is a power of 2

Tags: beginner, ruby

The task:

> Write a method that takes in a number and returns true if it is a power of 2. Otherwise, return false.
>
> You may want to use the `%` modulo operation. `5 % 2` returns the remainder when dividing 5 by 2; therefore, `5 % 2 == 1`. In the case of `6 % 2`, since 2 evenly divides 6 with no remainder, `6 % 2 == 0`."

Model solution:

> ```
> def is_power_of_two?(num)
>   if num < 1
>     return false
>   end
>
>   while true
>     if num == 1
>       return true
>     elsif num % 2 == 0
>       num = num / 2
>     else
>       return false
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

My solution:

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)

0.upto(num) do |i| 
  return true if 2**i == num
  return false if 2**i > num
end
end
```

This is a problem from a beginner's course. I'm trying to return to these problems now that I've learned some more idiomatic Ruby.

Generally, are there any advantages to the model solution? Specifically, how could I improve my solution?

Comment: @pycoder You mean something like this? 0.upto((num**0.5).round)

Comment: @pycoder it seems that when I run the code with the rounded square root, an input of 5 or 6 returns a zero, strangely....

Comment: Sorry, I should have said half of the number, my bad.

Comment: The `is_` prefix and the `?` suffix are redundant. If given a choice, I would go with `power_of_2?`.

Comment: `num % 2 == 0` is the same as `num.even?`.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these ultimately do a linear search trying one power of two after another to see if that one is equal to the input.

Depending on your intent, there's a way that might be better.

A power of two has exactly one bit set, so our job is really to determine whether only one bit is set in the number.

Let's consider a number with only one bit set: 000010000. If we subtract one from this number, we get: 000001111--that is, the least significant 0 bits in the number now become ones, and the least significant bit that was set becomes a 0.

Now, lets see what happens if we do the same to a number with two or more bits set. Let's consider 00010100. If we decrement it, we get 00010011. The same thing has happened--the least significant bit that was set has become a zero, the less significant bits have become one, and any more significant bits remain unchanged.

So, we can define our function as:

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
    return num & (num - 1) == 0
end
```

### Sumary

#### Pros

This has the advantage of being short, simple, and relatively fast.

#### Cons

It has the disadvantage that although the code is readable, many (especially less experienced programmers) may find the algorithm difficult to understand.

Comment: Well, it's like you read my mind! I just learned that upto method a couple days ago. Not quite up to the bitwise operators yet....thx for telling me like it is, all the same

Comment: I should probably add one point: the difference in speed here will often be fairly small: in many typical cases, numbers tend to be fairly small, so the iterative solutions may well iterate though only a small number of bits before finding their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since a power of 2 is always represented in binary form like this :

100...000, I would check if the binary representation contains exactly one '1' like this :

```
def power_of_two?(num)
  num.to_s(2).count('1') == 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can convert the number to binary string form and match it with a regex:

```
!!num.to_s(2)[/^10*$/]
```